# Why is scanf skipping the input here?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char another;
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the number");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("square of%d is %d\n", num, num * num);
        printf("want to check another number y/n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &another);
    } while (another == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the second `scanf()` is not getting executed and hence the console is not accepting input.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` oh no, just no. You need to remove that monstrosity and then `scanf("%c",&another);` -> `scanf(" %c",&another);`

Comment: Always check the result of scanf. *"scanf() is not getting executed"* is most likely not what's actually the problem.

Comment: Use scanf(" %c",&another) instead of scanf("%c",&another).

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard, flushing `stdin` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a number for the first scanf, its always followed by a newline. %d only takes the integer value and the newline is still left in the input buffer. So the subsequent scanf ends up consuming that character and your loop terminates due to another=='y' being false. (another has '\n').

Following is one of the ways to solve the problem. Use a %c along with %d to capture newline and ignore it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char another, nl;
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the number");
        scanf("%d%c",&num,&nl);
        printf("square of%d is %d\n",num,num*num);
        printf("want to check another number y/n: ");
        //fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&another);
        printf("%c", another);
    }while (another=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &another);` is a simpler solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you add the statement

```
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
```

it will move the stdin pointer to the end of the file so any extra character will be omitted. then write the second scanf. I mean:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char another, nl;
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("enter the number");
        scanf("%d%c",&num,&nl);
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        printf("square of%d is %d\n",num,num*num);
        printf("want to check another number y/n: ");
        //fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&another);
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        printf("%c", another);
    }while (another=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that on a Unix system, if standard input is a terminal, the terminal is not a seekable device, so the proposed `fseek()` would do nothing (or, rather, it would fail with error ESPIPE, Illegal seek).  If the input device was a file, it would, of course, seek to the end of the file; there'd be no further input unless the file grew between the time of the seek and the time of the `scanf()`.  So, on the whole, this is not a portable solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes you're right! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the char input before scanf dont work 
remove the fflush and add a space  to <<"%c">>
like this: scanf(" %c",&another);

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char another;

    int num;

    do
    {
        printf("enter the number ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("square of %d is %d\n",num,num*num);
        printf("want to check another number y/n ");
        scanf(" %c",&another);


    }while (another=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

This works great

Comment: testing the return value of both `scanf()` calls would be wise too.

Answer (score -1):

First of all fflush; flushes the output buffer of a stream, so you should not be using it here. The reason why the second scanf is not working is because you are trying to read a 1-bit character which in this case always getting the value of \0 after the second printf statement. Hope this helped.

Comment: Are you sure about `'\0'`? Should scanf read a newline `'\n'`?

Comment: I don't think you really meant a **1-bit character**, but I'm not sure what you actually do mean!